# How to get regex for 2011999

Tags: regex

Hei  !
can regex support 2011999
So we "force" the first 4 digits to be 2011 or 2012 ,2013 etc, and as a set of numbers behind it? Which means that it will be 2011 + 3 digits
the first digit must always be 2011 or 2012 etc?

How can I get this using regular expression?

Comment: *"2011 or 2012 etc?"*: **Which** values are allowed? To learn about regular expressions, have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the values you want. It's often better with these sort of questions to specify the *rules* rather than examples, since there may be many different ways to interpret the examples.

As a start, if you want the first four digits to be 201x where `x` is 1 thru 9 inclusive, followed by three digits, you could use something like:

```
^201[1-9][0-9]{3}$
```

(depending on the modern-ness of your regex engine.

Or, if you're processing things like `YYYYDDD` where `DDD` is the zero-based day of the year and you don't want any dates before 2011, you may end up with a monstrosity like:

```
^((201[1-9])|(20[2-9][0-9])|(2[1-9][0-9][0-9]))
    (([0-2][0-9][0-9])|(3[0-5][0-9])|(36[0-5]))$
```

(though only up to the year 2999 and allowing 366 days even in non-leap years) at which point you may want to consider just using (more readable) code rather than a regex :-)

That's the sort of range of possibilities you're looking at with a question along the lines of "must always be 2011 or 2012 etc" though, if you can lock down the specifications a little more, we can hopefully remove the more bizarre possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

20(10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20)[0-9]{2,4}

Answer (score 0):

You could use alternation:

/(2011|2012|2013)\d{3}/

But that's not very future proof.  A regex doesn't really support constraining values to a numeric range very well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\b201\d{4}\b
```

See your [regex on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vfna) a good place to learn and test  regular expressions

`\b` is a word boundary, that means before the first digit there is no digit and no letter (and no _) allowed.

This regex will find a number that starts with 201 followed by 4 digits.

If you want to restrict the starting number more you can do something like

```
\b201(?:1|2|3)\d{3}\b
```

or same meaning use a character class instead of alternation

```
\b201[123]\d{3}\b
```

Answer (score 0):

A non regexp way that's future proof

```
var validFutureYears = 5;
the_value= parseInt(the_value, 10);
var vyear = new Date().getFullYear() * 1000;
var isValid = the_value >= vyear && the_value <= vyear + (validFutureYears * 1000);
```